# Customize QML Tab Buttons

Tags: qt, tabs, qml

I'm looking to make a Tab-bar in QML that sits at the bottom and has rounded corners for any tabs that are on left and right-most edges as roughly depicted in the image below.
[image]

One way to achieve this is by hard coding the left and right-most buttons to appear that way, but I would like to avoid it because some tabs are dynamically added and removed. How can I customize the QML `TabButton` or `TabBar` control elements in a way so that any tab buttons on the edges end up with rounded corners?

I have tried modifying the background `Rectangle` item for the `TabButton` control, but any changes I make affect all the tabs. For example, if I try changing the background colors for tab buttons 1 and 2 using `color: (TabBar.index > 2) ? "red" : "blue"` all the tabs are colored blue. I have also tried `TabBar.tabBar.index` and that doesn't work either. I would appreciate any help in pointing out where I might be going wrong.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to u for reference.

[设置qml一边为圆角](https://blog.csdn.net/sono_io/article/details/114290256)

set one edge of rectangle to round corner

Comment: This is helpful in making the button the exact shape that I want, but it still requires that I specify for each button what shape it should be. How can this be handled dynamically (so that any button that's added to either end of the tab bar is shaped correctly without me specifying it)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using [count](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#count-prop) property, [index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html#index-attached-prop) property and [itemAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-container.html#itemAt-method) method:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1

Item {
    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: 1000
        Repeater {
            model: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth"]
            TabButton {
                text: modelData
                width: 100
                property int roundedEdge: 0 // 0 - no rounded edges, 1 - left side rounded, 2 - right side rounded
                background: Item
                {
                    Rectangle {
                        id:     roundRect
                        height: 100
                        width:  100
                        radius: roundedEdge == 0 ? 0 : 10
                        color:  "black"
                    }

                    Rectangle {
                        id:     leftSquareRect
                        visible: roundedEdge == 2
                        color:  "black"
                        height: roundRect.height
                        width:  roundRect.width - roundRect.radius
                        anchors.bottom : roundRect.bottom
                        anchors.left : roundRect.left
                    }
                    
                    Rectangle {
                        id:     rightSquareRect
                        visible: roundedEdge == 1
                        color:  "black"
                        height: roundRect.height
                        width:  roundRect.width - roundRect.radius
                        anchors.bottom : roundRect.bottom
                        anchors.right : roundRect.right
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        onCountChanged: {
            for(let i = 0; i < bar.count; i++)
            {
                if(i == 0)
                    bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 1
                else if(i == bar.count - 1)
                    bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 2
                else
                    bar.itemAt(i).roundedEdge = 0
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: bar.removeItem(bar.itemAt(1))
    }
}
```